# Angular Material Table only display items when click on table

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-material

Items only display on table, when I click on the table.

When first time loading the page, the table is empty. I don't know why.

I retrieve the data from Rest-API Cloud Blobstorage and then I fill the empty Array.

here is the code:

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
```

Here I export interface PeriodicElement

```
//name of table column
export interface PeriodicElement {
  timestamp: string;  //need to be declared as string, angular table module requires it
  key: string;
  value: number;

}
```

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['timestamp', 'key', 'value'];

ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = new Array<PeriodicElement>();

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
data_array: Array<JsonSchema> = [];

@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;  //sort data 
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;  //for displaying data in the tables

constructor( privat DataStreamService: DataStreamService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

this.DataStreamService.getContents().then(results => {
this.data = results
......
....

....cut code .... 

this.ELEMENT_DATA.push(...tabledata)


}
```

On Browser View, when Table is rendered.
when I click on items per page data loads, before that it shows an empty table.

maybe you guys know how to fix it.
I spend days and didn't find the problems. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use a loadingData boolean. And why you use Promises in Angular? Try [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables). This is not React, or plain JS, is Angular with TypeScript and we use RxJs for data streaming.

```
export class YourComponent extends OnInit {

    loadingData = false;

     constructor(
         // try to make a difference here between
         // an instance started with "lowercase" and the service name
         private dataStreamService: DataStreamService
     ) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    
        this.loadingData = true;
        this.dataStreamService.getContents().subscribe(results => {
           this.data = results;
           this.loadingData = false;
        });
    }
}
```

in your html use *ngIf directive on table container tab:

```
<div *ngIf="!loadingData">
  <table>
   ... your content
  </table>
</div>
```

and your service method became :

```
getContent(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get<any_type>(url).pipe()
     .tap(response => {
        // here you can modelate your data
        return response;
     });
}
```

because `getContent()` is an asyncronous code, you need to rerender your html after data is loaded. Using `loadingData` attribute, you will tell the angular when must to rerender the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.DataStreamService.getContents().then(results => {
  this.data = results; 
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
});
```