# Angular - cannot display data from API into the template

Tags: angular

I am making a call to the API and I can get the data properly and display it in the console. But when I try to make it visible in the template, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="posts.length !== 0">
  Posts list: {{posts | json}}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts">{{post.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="posts.length === 0">
  There are no posts
</div>
```

Component:

```
getData() {
   this.myService.getData().subscribe(
      function(data) {
        this.posts = data;
        console.log('Data FROM SERVICE: ', this.posts);  //  This works!
        
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }
```

It is always displaying `There are no posts`. So even if I assign the `data` to `this.posts`, I cannot display it in template. Do I have to run the change detection manually, or what is wrong here?
If I try to use an `async` pipe, it is working, but I would like to have it working also in the way I described above. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: you need to use a boolean to tell the dom to rerender the template after loading data. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719684/angular-material-table-only-display-items-when-click-on-table/63719970#63719970. and you can rennounce at this adnotation: subscribe(function(data) { ... }) to subscribe(data => { ... })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about `this` context. When you use `function(xx)`, `this` is not what you think it is. Always use arrow functions:

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe(
  (data) => { // <== arrow function here
    this.posts = data;
    console.log('Data FROM SERVICE: ', this.posts);  //  This works!
    
  },
  (err) => { // <== arrow function here
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

Also, you need to add safety to your HTML (the null-safe-operator `?`), when `posts` is null (not yet retrieved):

```
<div *ngIf="posts?.length !== 0">
<div *ngIf="posts?.length === 0">
```

Comment: The `this` was the problem, indeed. Regarding the template changes you mentioned, I am declaring 'posts' at the beginning as an empty array, so there is no need for checking for the existence of `posts`. Anyway, you couldn't know that, so it's a good advice. Thanks!